# simple PHP multiple file upload does not send files to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

I have this code

```
<form method="post" id="usrForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" multiple accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.gif" name="fl[]"/>
</form>

//Some Other tags and elements
<input type="button" id="formSubmit" onclick="$('#usrForm').submit()"/>
```

In php, when I echo **print_r($_FILES["fl"])** I get empty array like this

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )
```

and therefore I cannot upload any images etc. What am I doing wrong? I have been wondering for about 3 hours searching different articles but all in vein.

Comment: your update code works fine for me, please  try print_r($_FILES);

Comment: What browser are you using, some relatively new browsers (IE9 for example) still don't support multiple files selection

Comment: Ok I think then it's IE. Lemme Check it

Comment: No it's not working even in latest Mozilla firefox and chrome as well

Answer (score 1):

you should define enctype 
use

```
<form method="post" id="usrForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

insted of

```
<form method="post" id="usrForm">
```

**update**

your code works fine

make sure file upload is On, on php.ini

```
file_uploads = On;
```

Comment: SOrry RezSh but I just forgot to mention that but I have added that

Comment: I have updated my question plz see i have already added enctype in my real code but still that hungs

Comment: so let me check your question again

Comment: please check fileupload throw phpinfo() once again, you may edit invalid php.ini file ? your code works fine for me in chrome and firefox